# Favicon não aparece no front-end chrome

Tags: wordpress, favicon

Sou novo no wordpress e preciso de uma ajuda, 
meu site carrega o favicon em quase os navegadores sem problemas.
Só não aparece no chrome, mas apenas no front-end.

Quando eu abro o admin, o favicon aparece sem problemas, mas no site ele não aparece.

Já tentei limpar o cache, mudar o código de todas as maneiras que encontrei no google
mas esse problema persiste.

minha header está assim:

```
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_directory");?>/bootstrap-4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Css custom -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo("template_directory");?>/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo("template_directory");?>/style.css">

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="<?php bloginfo("template_directory");?>/fav512.png" />

<title>Setormed</title>
</head>
```

tentei mudar pelo código e pelo painel de admin, mas em nenhum dos dois modos consegui o resultado certo.

Estou desde ontem sem solução para isso e preciso arrumar o mais rapido possível.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Cara muitas vezes o browser fica com o favicon no cache e fica mostrando errado na aba. Vc já tentou limpar o cache, reiniciar a maquina e o browser etc para ver se resolve?

Comment: Já limpei o cache e reiniciei o pc umas 1000 vezes. O problema continua.

Comment: O mais estranho é que no painel de admin ele funciona.

Comment: Não sei se é o caso do tema que vc usou, mas em alguns deles vc tem o CSS e página do config do template do Administrador e Outro CSS com a config do template da página principal no front. As vezes vc só colocou o Favicon pra página ADM e não no template do site.